# How can I use the node.js v8 module in a react app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to use the serialization API from the node.js v8 module in my react app (created with create-react-app) but it doesn't seem to work.

According to the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/v8.html) it should just be a case of importing/requiring the module. When I try this, it all appears to be working as expected - no errors. I can even access methods like .serialize() and .deserialize() on the v8 object too - great. But when I try to actually run my project (using react-scripts start) I get a compilation error:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'v8' in '...'
```

Is it looking for a file called "v8.js" to import rather than using the node module for some reason? How do I get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

node_modules is only a concept when working within the node ecosystem. So it is only possible to import "v8" when within a node process.

Since you ask about a "react app" that seems to imply that you are writing something for the browser. Which now has modules which use import/export (similar to require/module.exports from node), however, that still doesn't mean that the "v8" package will be present.

Many of node's packages are C++ backed (or to use the technical term, they are "native packages") instead of being purely written in JS. Also, it should be noted that unlike dependencies listed in your "package.json" file, none of the node packages are actually downloaded when you run `npm install` since they are all bundled with your installation of node.