# How to use the 'v8' module in react native?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, v8

I am having trouble using the v8 module in my react native app (running on node version v16.14.0). I would like to use the `structuredClone()` [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone) introduced in node v17. To do this I tried to access the v8 module and use the [Serialization API](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/v8.html#v8_serialization_api) like so (the link suggests this module should be available in node v16).

```
const v8 = require('v8');
// Remove in newer versions of Node that natively support structuredClone
const structuredClone = (o) => v8.deserialize(v8.serialize(o));
```

When I try to run this on my android phone using expo I get "Unable to resolve module v8 from C:\Users... v8 could not be found within the project or in these directories:
node_modules"

Which I think sounds like it is trying to search my project rather than the v8 module installed with node. Any ideas why this is?

EDIT: Seems [this answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69981262/17888937). Alternatively, it might be possible to make it usable by using this [react-native-v8](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-v8) package. Can't confirm as I haven't used it.

Comment: android phone does not have `C:`

Comment: You mean it doesn't have the v8 module? I'm pretty new to all this so I don't fully understand it but doesn't it run on node which has v8 as a module?

Comment: no, I do not mean that ... C: is a drive letter of an MS-DOS type of a file system ... android does not use the MS-DOS file system

Comment: Yeah so when you run it through expo I think it uses the files on your computer to build the project or something. Anyways, any idea why it can't find this module?

Comment: i just told you twice ... android knows nothing about C: drive

Comment: As I said I am new to this so sorry if this is a dumb question but where is it looking then? To be clear I have the project on my computer and I use npm start to run it then scan the QR code with my android phone in the expo app. It obviously has access to all the other modules that I installed in the project somehow (such as react-native-gesture-handler etc) so what's the difference with this one?